# How to generate Autopoco data when object has protected contructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autopoco

Im getting an "**No parameterless constructor defined for this object**" exception when trying to generate data for the following object:

```
public class User  
{
    protected User();
    public User(string userName, string password);
}
```

this is the line that throws the error:

```
// Get 10 users
var users = pocoSession.List<User>(10).Get();
```

Comment: What is this `pocoSession.List<User>(10)`? How is it generating data?

Comment: It is the standard syntax for generating data in Autopoco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is `protected`, which means it's only visible to inheriting classes. You need to make it `public` in order to be able to construct the type:

```
public User()
{
   // Do stuff.
}
```

**Edit:**

As you can see [here](https://autopoco.codeplex.com/workitem/12), AutoPoco doesn't *currently* support constructor arguments (which is from 2011, doesn't seem promising).

Comment: I know, but that is not an option

Comment: Why is that not an option? How do you expect to create the type? Why would you make a `public` class if you don't want to instantiate it *publicly*?

Comment: Oh, you only want to make the constructor with parameters available?

Comment: Yeap, it can only be instantiated with parameters :(

Comment: Have you considered [*other mocking frameworks*](http://jimmykeen.net/2014/12/13/mocking-frameworks-comparison/)?